# Yii Understanding model creation

Tags: php, yii

Im wondering if someone could give me some help.

I'm very new to the Yii framework and im taking over some code for a friend.

Would someone be kind enough to tell me what the following lines do.

```
$variable = new ModuleModel('search');
$another->columns = $variable->search()->data;
```

I've never seen something passed when creating a new model instance and im not sure what the 'data' call does.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: print `$variable->search()` to check what it returns

Answer (score 0):

> `$variable = new ModuleModel('search');`

this line call a method search() from class ModuleModel. This is used with CGridView for searching and filtering you will find somwthing helpful [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/142/search-method-of-a-model-for-filters-when-using-dates-unixtimestamp-in-database/)

> `$variable->search()->data`

This is accesing property from object where  $variable->search() will return object and data is property of an object it's same as an

```
$searchData = $variable->search();

$searchData->data;
```

finally this line

> `$another->columns = $variable->search()->data;`

assign data property from $variable->search() to $another->columns

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so data is a Yii function? Is there a way to show only specific columns from this?

Comment: data is an property of an class. use print( $variable->getData() ) to print whatever data return. and share this data for more clear full  understanding